# Karma - Injecting Angular InjectionToken problem

Tags: angular, unit-testing, dependency-injection, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test a component which injects an InjectionToken, which I have created. For testing I'm using default @angular/cli configuration for Karma.

But I'cant get around this error:

```
NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken path.configuration!
```

I've tried to provide my token inside providers when using TestBed.configureTestingModule like this:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [RouterTestingModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: PATH_CONFIGURATION, useValue: { LOGIN: '/login' }
    }
  ],
  declarations: [HeaderComponent],

}).compileComponents();
```

My InjectionToken definition is this:

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
export interface PathConfiguration {
    LOGIN: string;
}
export const pathConfiguration: PathConfiguration = {
    LOGIN: '/login'
}
export const PATH_CONFIGURATION = new InjectionToken<PathConfiguration>('path.configuration');
```

And this is the way how I inject it inside the component:

```
constructor(
    @Inject(PATH_CONFIGURATION) private pathConfig: PathConfiguration
) { }
```

I've read some posts on stackoverflow that this is the way to provide injectionToken inside test enviroment. But as I said there is no luck for me.

Am I doing something wrong? Or should I set some other property inside some configuration file beforehand?

Comment: any solution for the above mentioned problem?